# Hive Drop and Create table says 'Table already exists'

Tags: python, hive, hiveql

I am running a python script which drops a table if exists in Hive and then it recreates the table. But when create script is running, it throws an error 'Table already exists'. Can some one help why Hive is behaving like this and possible solution for this.

Following are my queries:

filters_drop = drop table if exists {database}.{table_name};

filters_create =
create table {database}.{table_name}
as
select * from some_table';

Comment: not sure about your code - how are you calling it ? mind sharing actual code?